# Access SharePoint Online via REST API

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

Having problem with accessing sharepoint via rest api.

Hi!

I'm trying to use REST API to access company SharePoint Online in Python.

For instance, the SharePoint folder I want to access is:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/foldername. I have access to the site, and the folder, but no access to the company root.

I tried two methods:

Option 1: `HttpNtlmAuth`

domain =  ' https://company.sharepoint.com/'

```
url = ' https://marvell.sharepoint.com/sites/sse/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'Sandbox\')/items'

actual_username = domain + username

response = requests.get(sharePointUrl,auth= HttpNtlmAuth(actual_username,password))
```

Option 2: `sharepy`

```
s = sharepy.connect("company.sharepoint.com")
```

But both of them fails, and I get either `403, Forbidden`, or `401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url`.

Can anyone help to check what might be the issue here?

Thanks in advance!

C.

Answer (score -2):

The following solutions with source code from GitHub for your reference.

[Office 365 API SDK for Python](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client)

[SharePy - Simple SharePoint Online authentication for Python](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy)